# Слово "совесть"

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы узнать этимологию слова "совесть".

Answer (score 1):

Заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз. В памятниках письменности отмечается с XI в. Ст.-сл. съвѢсть является калькой греч. syneidesis «совесть», собств. «сознание долга», из *syn-* со 
знач. совокупности, соответствующего рус. *со-*, и *eideso* «буду знать, 
узнаю», ср. *eidos* «осведомленность». Эти слова восходят к и.-е. yeid-/*(w)id- «видеть», «ведать». Для перевода использована прист. съ- и глаг. вѢдати «знать». Ср. в др.-рус. яз. 
слово съвѢсть значило «разумение, понимание» и «совесть». Стар. форма съвѢсть из первонач. съвЬдть. Сочетание дт изменилось в тт > cт. Звучание* совесть *(а не* свесть*) является искусственно-книжным, т. е. это слово вошло в рус. яз. из ц.-слав. книг.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в Церковно-славянском словаре Г. Дьяченко словарной статьи нет, можно понимать её отсутствие как возможность трактовать *совесть* либо как указание на  её врождённость, либо как пробуждение или воспитуемость этого чувства в человеке независимо от религиозности какого-либо общества. Тогда получается, что наличие совести (второго я, чувства меры допустимого, осознания собственного достоинства) ощущается всяким разумным человеком как внутренний голос, помогающий ему ***вести*** себя, видеть себя объёмно и контролировать поступки на уровне слова.

Придерживаюсь этой версии, где в составе слова *со-весть* закреплена роль соведущего, сопровождающего, сотрудничающего сознания.